# Error: 1064 error in sql query

Tags: mysql

This sql query generates `Error 1064` in Mysql:

```
CREATE table batch(id number primary key, 
                   batchNumber varchar2(20), 
                   InitialDate date, 
                   UpdateDate date);
```

I'm not sure how to resolve that error after trying several things.

Comment: Can you post the full error message? Also, what did you try to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
Create table batch(id integer primary key,batchNumber varchar(20),InitialDate date,UpdateDate date);
```

I don't think `number` is a mysql data type (I used `integer`) and neither is `varchar2` (I used `varchar`).

For reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html